# Positive value input C

Tags: c, function, recursion, input

The idea of this function is to ask for a positive value, and make sure a negative one is not inserted using recursion.

However when I test it, if the first value I enter is negative, while the function works and does not allow the code to proceed until a positive value is entered, the code still prints the very first value inserted, regardless if it fulfilled the requirements for the return.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float scanval()
{
  float x;
  printf("Insert positive value \n");
  scanf("%f", &x);

  if(x<0){
    printf("Not a valid value \n");
    scanval();
  }

  return x;
}

main()
{
  printf("Value given %f \n", scanval());
}
```

Comment: You really don't want to use recursion for this - use a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should remember to save the return value:

```
x = scanval()
```

inside the function.

Comment: You should be explicit about where that has to be, I thought you were wrong at first.

Comment: @iharob - I added "inside the function". Does that make it clear?

Answer (score 0):

First recognize that recursion is not the appropriate technique here.
You should be using a ***while*** loop.

But if you need recursion for whatever homework purposes:

```
float scanval()
{
  float x;
  printf("Insert positive value \n");
  scanf("%f", &x);

  if (x<0){                          // While x is negative, 
    printf("Not a valid value \n"); // Showing an error message, 
    x = scanval();                 // Try the routine again.
  }

  return x;
}
```

Comment: He is not asking for a real life solution, rather for how to solve this specific problem WITH recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following trivially:

```
    if(x<0){
    printf("Not a valid value \n");
    return scanval();
  }
```

Of course, best practice is to only have a single return in a function, but I don't think you care about that since you're trying to accomplish this task with recursion!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do, is this

```
float scanval()
{
    float x;

    printf("Insert positive value \n");

    if ((scanf("%f", &x) != 1) || (x < 0))
    {
        int chr;
        while (((chr = getchar()) != EOF) && (chr != '\n'));
        return scanval();
    }
    return x;
}
```

notice that I also check if the input was valid, on valid input `scanf()` will return `1` in this case, so checking for that is also important.

And you also need to remove the remaining whitespace from the input buffer, for which you can use this

```
int chr;
while (((chr = getchar()) != EOF) && (chr != '\n'));
```

If you don't check for valid input, you risk accessing `x` when it's uninitialized leading to undefined behavior.